# how to scrape web page using dynamic urls in PhantomJs

Tags: c#, web-scraping

By using simple hard coded url its works fine

```
 var phantomJS = new PhantomJS();
 phantomJS.RunScript(@"var page = require('webpage').create();
                                            page.open('http://search4best.com',
                                            function(){var arg = page.evaluate(function(){return document.getElementById('form_div').innerHTML;})
                                            console.log(arg);
                                            phantom.exit();})", new string[]{}, null, null);
```

but problem is i'm trying to scrape web page using dynamical urls

```
  var url = "http"//search4best.com";    
    string JavaScript = "var page = require('webpage').create();"
                                                +"page.open('"+url+"',function()"+
                                                "{var arg = page.evaluate(function(){return document.getElementById('form_div').innerHTML})"+
                                                "console.log(arg)phantom.exit()})";
    
phantomJS.RunScript(@JavaScript, new string[] {},null,null);
```

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Something goes wrong isn't exactly a description of your problem. Does it throw an error, crash, set your building on fire?

Comment: i'm edit my question again and there is no still response. no error no crash   please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

yet i'm solved problem by using verbatim string

```
 string JavaScript = string.Format(@"var page = require('webpage').create();
                                                page.open('{0}',function(){{var arg = page.evaluate(
                                                function(){{return document.getElementById('form_div').innerHTML;}})
                                                console.log(arg);phantom.exit();}})", query);

                    phantomJS.RunScript(JavaScript, new string[] {
                    });
```